# Do virtual particles have a density?

Tags: gravity, probability, density, virtual-particles

I am currently working with some theory that predicts that virtual particles would have a higher density (higher chance of appearing) in strong gravity field and would move towards gravity force. I cannot find any info about it. Is this even possible? Do virtual particles appearing chance depends on something or its more like some constant per space cube meter?

Comment: How does your theory define and quantify virtual particles' number density, and predict it's increased in strong gravity? This may help us ascertain what analogous findings of [mainstream theories](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4539) would interest you.

Comment: I would say their density gets less in highly curved space. They are stretched and near a black hole even excited to real particles.

Comment: I hate to have to bring it to you, but virtual particles are a purely mathematical construct. They don’t exist in reality.

Comment: @Oбжорoв Then what do they describe ? The math has a counterpart in reality, or doesn't it? To say to "shut up and calculate" is the easy way out. There **is** something going on in the vacuum...

Comment: @Felicia It is not "shut up and calculate" they really are mathematical artifacts from the perturbative expansion used.